# Firebase functions invocation/executaion limit is a pain

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am using firebase hosting and functions together to convert PDF TO IMAGE.

For that i wrote a function which takes the file and converts the pdf upload it storage, generates a signedURL and returns it to the user.

In hosting i wrote a rewrite which redirects request from /ecc to ecc function.

Setup worked Well. Website is up and running.

But when i asked a small group of 100 people to use it.

Then firebase functions started throwing err 429 which is too many requests.

Is there any limit on executing functions in 100 Seconds ?

This is the log:

> Error: quota exceeded (Quota exceeded for quota group 'CPUMilliSecondsNonbillable' and limit 'CPU allocation in function invocations per 100 seconds' of service 'cloudfunctions.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:992192007775'.); to increase quotas, enable billing in your project at https://console.cloud.google.com/billing?project=myProject. Function cannot be executed.
> {"serviceContext":{"service":"ecc"},"context":{"reportLocation":{"functionName":"ecc","lineNumber":0,"filePath":"file"}}}

And in Firebase pricing it says that 125K invocation per month is free but with 40K GB and CPU seconds.

So if i have a function with execution time of 10 seconds i can call only 4000 functions per month ? and with that 16 calls per 100 seconds Limit. where are other 121K function?

**Updated Information from Quotas**

It's really a head banging thing to understand the limits here this is the main quota page

[image: QUOTA PAGE]

**FUNCTION EXECUTION TIME IS 10 SECOND. AND I'LL CALCULATE THINGS ON THAT.**

- `1,2. CPU allocation in function Invocation PerDay` : `150K`.
  first two are same for some reason.
- `3. CPU allocation in function invocation per 100 seconds`: `100k(0.1% CurrentUsage)`.
  means per 100 second i can "invoke" 10k function.
- `4. Function invocation per 100 seconds`:`50`. Okay Leave The 3rd Point aside.
- `5. Read Request Per Day`: `50` Maybe same as 4th ?
- `6. Function invocation per day` : `5000` I was having a dream until 4th point opened my eyes.
- `7. Write request per day` : `1000` Function deployment maybe ?
- `8. Write request per 100 seconds`: `20` That's Okay.

Now with all that in mind i can say i can execute 50 functions per 100 seconds.

What my error was `QUOTA EXCEEDED 'CPU allocation in function invocations per 100 seconds'`

but as per the QUOTA the CPU ALLOC IN FUN INV PER 100 SECOND is 100K !!! ??

How it even exceeded the limit ?

as i said my function execution is about 5-10 seconds and with the invocation limit, maximum seconds would be 500.

What is going on ?, Why QUOTA is exceeding ?
what's the difference beetwen `Read` and `Invoking` a function ?

Comment: are you sure this is what are you using? as the documentation [says](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/quotas#footnote) this CALL api is meant for testing and not for production and that's why it's limited

Comment: This is what i can relate to. I tried my self, used website with my friends to make sure. And yeah the rate limit was popping in the firebase functions logs.

Comment: what trigger are you using for your functions and how are you triggering them?

Comment: I am using Hosting and redirecting a webpage request to function using `XMLHttprequest` and sending file and password as form data. I've updated the log to main question.

Comment: @MethkalKhalawi i am calling the function via redirection through hosting and not using any triggers.

Answer (score 1):

From the error it seems that you have exceeded the quota for Firebase Functions (CPU) per month and as you are using free tier then it's only **40K** per month.

Using Firebase Functions in Free tier (Spark) is very limited and it's only for **Node 8**.

To resolve this you need to upgrade to Blaze plan (pay as you go). which also has free tier:

CPU --> Free up to 200K/month

Please, read more about this [here](https://firebase.google.com/pricing)

Comment: I know pricing of functions and how they works. But the problem here is 16 calls per 100 Seconds API LIMIT. I mentioned it before when website will have 100 concurrent users it will simply throw 429 error to 84 of them which is ridiculously bad.

Comment: as I said before this limit is for testing and you should never us it in production. we can agree that 100 concurrent users is not testing anymore. [documentation says](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/quotas#footnote): **You cannot increase the CALL quota. Insufficient quota generally occurs if you mistakenly use this API to invoke your functions in production. Please keep in mind that this API is meant for testing via Cloud Console or ' gcloud functions call CLI, and it cannot handle heavy traffic.**

Comment: Confusions, i don't know which `api` this page is referring to, i read it again and it's unclear to me. I wanted to execute a function named ecc and i deployed it using firebase cli. and i am using hosting and wrote an rewrite which redirects /ecc page request to ecc function which then executes the function `ecc`. Now while in this process the quota limit is coming. Where is the problem ?

Comment: I've updated the main question completely. Please take a look if you can now understand the situation well.

Comment: Hi, you cannot relate quotas to each others. everyone of them has different purpose and once you hit the limit of one of them then you cannot use functions any more. the only thing that you can do here is to upgrade your firebase billing to blaze.

Comment: @Hey Methkal please see OP section `Updated Information from Quotas` and try to understand the situtaion.

Comment: You are confusing yourself between two things, Firebase pricing and GCP pricing are different. you are talking about firebase but sharing a dashboard from GCP quota console. You cannot depend on that as GCP doesn't have the concept of free tier and data in this page doesn't actually reflect your Firebase limits. if you check firebase [pricing](https://firebase.google.com/pricing) you can see that spark tier has only 40 CPU seconds per month and that's 8K functions invocations per month in case of 5s function. This probably what's causing the CPU quota error.

Comment: also, please keep in mind that Node 8 Firebase functions will be deprecated soon. so you should really consider upgrade to Node 10

Comment: i was suggested to look there, and i don't see any detailed information same as i found in GCP. For instance, the per 100 limits i was never able to find that and still haven't yet discovered that in firebase documentations. And the questions that were answered before about this on stackoverflow, stated  `check `GCP CF daily limits`` I guess those are old enough now but still Firebase Documentation lack information about daily limits i think. and firebase documentation itself says to check GCP to edit or view quotas. see https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/quotas

Comment: So in GCP the function invocation limit is 50 and in firebase it's 16 ? Am i right ? and about upgrading to Node 10 i don't think any bank will give a student a credit card. I hope GCP will introduce some `wallet` kind options. which will work for most of the beginners. If not than i guess have to look at other free options.

Comment: I think you are mixing things. You are hitting CPU-seconds quota, it has 40k per month limit but most likely also has per 100 seconds limit which you are hitting. Upgrade to Blaze as recommended as it has more generous free tier.